# Ordenar registros por cantidad definida

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente Query.

```
SELECT * FROM EMISORAS TE
INNER JOIN SUCURSALES S ON S.NUM_ = TE.NUM_
WHERE ISR <= .16 AND HTP <= .03 AND TTB <=.06
ORDER BY ISR DESC, HTP DESC, TTBDESC
```

Pero necesito mostrar los demas registros, es decir que el Where no me funcionaria por lo cual yo me imagino algo de esta manera.

```
SELECT * FROM EMISORAS TE
INNER JOIN SUCURSALES S ON S.NUM_ = TE.NUM_
ORDER BY PENETRACION <= .16 AND ICV <= .03 AND RESERVAS <=.06
```

Que primero tome los filtros que le estoy dando y despues me muestre los demas registros.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el operador [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) para traer primero tus registros filtrados y unes todos los demás:

```
SELECT * FROM EMISORAS TE
INNER JOIN SUCURSALES S ON S.NUM_ = TE.NUM_
WHERE ISR <= .16 AND HTP <= .03 AND TTB <=.06

UNION

SELECT * FROM EMISORAS TE
INNER JOIN SUCURSALES S ON S.NUM_ = TE.NUM_
WHERE ISR > .16 AND HTP > .03 AND TTB >.06

ORDER BY ISR, HTP, TTB
```

Comment: Sigo en lo mismo ya que necesito agregar el ORDER BY para ISR,HTP  y TTB lo cual sigue dando del mismo resultado, tengo que mostrar en la consulta ISR <= .16 AND HTP <= .03 AND TTB <=.06 ya que despues los muestro en una tabla y las personas quieren ver primero estos registros y despues los que no estan dentro de los paramentros que piden

Comment: A ver editaré la respueta agregando un ORDER BY

Comment: No funciona, la primera consulta se pierde al hacer el union con la segunda consulta

Comment: En teoria deberia funcionar, los campos de la primera consulta no deberian desaparecer. cuantos registro te devuelve ejecutar solo la primera consulta?

Comment: Una disculpa, ya modifique la pregunta no me percate que me falto agregar el order by

Answer (score 0):

Levi, si mal no entiendo lo que quieres es mostrar los datos en un orden especifico, primero unos definidos y luego el resto. Si es así, puedes emplear un CASE anidado en el ORDER BY de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Tabla2 AS t2 ON t1.campo1 = T2.campo2
ORDER BY 
CASE t1.campo1
    WHEN 'valor1' THEN  1
ELSE
    CASE t1.campo1
        WHEN 'valor2' THEN  2
    ELSE
        CASE t2.campo2
            WHEN 'valor3' THEN  3
        ELSE 4
        END
    END
END
```

Lo que no encuentro posible es validar con operadores en el ORDER BY, para ello se me ocurre tal vez, usar un campo adicional (llámese) 'ID' y asignar un ID según el valor, este se me ocurre que lo podrías hacer usando un CASE similar desde el SELECT.